I converted my .ipynb file into a .py script but when I run it, it does not work. (VS Code)
What i'm trying to do in this notebook is reading the file "updated_coffee_sales_data.xls" with Pandas, cleaning the file, and then exporting it into another excel file. This work with Notebooks but I want to slowly learn how to do this in Python scripts.
I tried just normal export and removed all the #%% markdowns and all, when I try to run, it does now work
# # **DATA CLEANING, WRANGLING, AND MANIPULATION**
# 
# **(Before Data Visualization)**

# ## Importing Pandas and creating DataFrames
# 
# First I import necessary packages and create a DataFrame for each sheet.

import pandas as pd
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()

df1 = pd.read_excel(pwd + r'\updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='transactions')
df2 = pd.read_excel(pwd + r'\updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='employees')
df3 = pd.read_excel(pwd + r'\updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='coffee')

# Then I check to see if there are any columns with mismatched Dtypes

df1.info()

df2.info()

df3.info()

# ## Merging tables
# 
# Everything looks fine so I can proceed.
# 
# In this case, I will join all of the tables together to create one DataFrame.
# 
# The first step to achieving this is to rename the columns and make the match across all DataFrames.

df1 = df1.rename(columns=
          {'Transaction ID' : 'trn_id', 'Emp_id' : 'emp_id',
          'Employee Name' : 'emp_name', 'Date and Time' : 'date_time',
          'Purchased Coffee Type' : 'coffee_type', 'Purchase Quantity' : 'purchase_qty',
          'Payment Method' : 'pay_method', 'Customer Name' : 'customer_name'}
     ) 
df2 = df2.rename(columns=
          {'Emp_id' : 'emp_id', 'Emp_Name' : 'emp_name',
          'Job Title' : 'job_title', 'Hourly Salary' : 'hr_salary'}
     )
df3 = df3.rename(columns=
          {'Coffee type' : 'coffee_type'}
     )

# Now that everything is named properly, I can merge the three DataFrames with no problems.

df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on='emp_id', how='inner').merge(df3, on='coffee_type', how='inner')
df_merged.head()

# ## Data cleaning.
# 
# Now it is finally time to clean the data.
# 
# From what I can see, there are a few changes that I can make:
# 1. Shorten the transaction IDs to the first 8 string.
# 2. Drop 1 employee name column 'emp_name_y" and renaming "emp_name_x".
# 3. Separate the date and time then drop the column 'date_time'
# 4. Rearrange the columns.
# 5. Finishing touches.

df_cleaning = df_merged.copy() # Always best practice to create new copies of your dataframes.

df_cleaning['trn_id'] = df_cleaning['trn_id'].str[:8] # Shorten the transaction IDs to the first 8 string.
df_cleaning = df_cleaning.rename(columns={'emp_name_x' : 'emp_name'}) # Drop 1 employee name column 'emp_name_y" and renaming "emp_name_x".
df_cleaning = df_cleaning.drop(columns=['emp_name_y'])
df_cleaning['date'] = df_cleaning['date_time'].dt.date # Separate the date and time then drop the column 'date_time'
df_cleaning['time'] = df_cleaning['date_time'].dt.time
df_cleaning = df_cleaning.drop(columns=['date_time'])
df_cleaning.head()

# Rearrange the columns.
reorder = [
     'trn_id', 'emp_id', 'hr_salary', 'job_title', 'emp_name',
     'date', 'time', 'coffee_type', 'purchase_qty', 'price',
     'total_price', 'pay_method', 'customer_name'
]

df_reorder = df_cleaning[reorder]
df_reorder.head()

df_reorder.info()

# Upon inspection, I noticed that date is Dtype Objects which will be a problem if not fixed.
# 
# Let me fix that.

df_dt = df_reorder.copy() # Always best practice to create new copies of your dataframes.


df_dt['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dt['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_dt.info()

df_dt.head()

# ## Exporting to CSV
# 
# Now that the data is clean and ready for visualization.
# I am going to export it into a csv file.

df_final = df_dt.copy()
df_final.to_csv('updated_coffee_sales_cleanedPY.csv', index=False)


I try running the import and the pwd = os.getcwd() in an interactive notebook first then try to run it again still did not work.
I can't copy the error in the terminal but what it's saying is:
[Errno 2]No such file or directory: 'D:\\Admin Files\\Desktop\DataS Proj\\Pproj_Coffee'


Remember that Python looks for files in the "current directory", which is NOT the directory that contains the script.  Your error doesn't make much sense, since that path never occurs in the source code.

@TimRoberts
The script is in the same folder as the xlsx that is why I used:
`
import os
pwd = os.getcwd()
df1 = pd.read_excel(pwd + r'\updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='transactions')

It is hard to replicate and help. Did you try to print out pwd in both environments and compare?

@gtomer I already found a solution. check the answer below. Yes, I tried to print our pwd and it was correct. but idk why Python did not like that. or maybe it was the '+' because when I used "os.path.join" it worked so I'm satisfied now.

I found the issue... Python had a problem with locating file because of who I told it to locate the path:
import pandas as pd
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()

df1 = pd.read_excel(pwd + r'\updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='transactions')
df2 = pd.read_excel(pwd + r'\updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='employees')
df3 = pd.read_excel(pwd + r'\updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='coffee')

What I should've done is to use "os.path.join" and the best solution is to also make that entire file path into a variable.
import os
import pandas as pd

# Get the current working directory
pwd = os.getcwd()

# Construct file paths
file_path = os.path.join(pwd, 'updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx')

# Read Excel files
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='transactions')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='employees')
df3 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='coffee')

This solution works for me. (I found another problem when I exported the file but fixed it using the same concept of actually defining the file path)

Consider using pathlib for working with paths in python.

I will look into it... thanks @Erik

It is nothing to do with your "pwd" but with the following path.
Try replacing "\" with "/" in "df1,df2,df3" as follows:
df1 = pd.read_excel(pwd + '/updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='transactions')
df2 = pd.read_excel(pwd + '/updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='employees')
df3 = pd.read_excel(pwd + '/updated_coffee_sales_data.xlsx', sheet_name='coffee')


If I remember correctly. using "/" is for Mac and "" is for windows. I am using windows. I will try this later and see if it works.
